# Magento 2 : change layout of catalogsearch module in design section

Tags: magento2, layout

Magento 2.1.7

Just only want to change layout structure of a `catalogsearch/result/index` module, from `2columns-left` to `1column`.

For which i copied layout file and made necessary changes and put it into the below location -

`/app/design/frontend/<Namespace>/<ThemeName>/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

Let me know please if i am doing any thing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  You just have to create a catalogsearch_result_index.xml (as you listed that you did above), then change the layout attribute for the page element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
  </body>
</page>
```